# clicking on calendar icon in the editext for the first time is not showing the datepicker dialog

Tags: android

Hai I have editext in my app where we can set the date of birth. in that editext I have a calendar icon. If we click on calendar icon it should open the datepicker dialog. But in my case if I click on calendar icon it is showing paste, clicpboard, selectall options in my editext instead of showing the date picker dialog and if we click on the calendar  icon again for the second time it is opening the date picker dialog. How to make the datepicker dialog open for the first click on my calendar icon. I alreadt set setFocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode to false but no use. please help to fix the same.

This is the fragment where I am having edittext for date of birth:

```
public class RegistrationBasicInformationFragment extends Fragment implements
        IRegistrationBasicInformationView, IRegistrationItemEventListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener {

    private TextView mRegistrationEnterYourBasicInformationLabel;
    private RelativeLayout mRegistrationBasicInformationMainLayout;
    private DsmApplication mDsmApplication;

    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice;
    private RegistrationItemView mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider;
    private RegistrationBasicInformationController mRegistrationBasicInformationController;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration_basicinformation_view_v222, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mDsmApplication = (DsmApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
        loadController();
        loadView(view);
    }

    private void loadController() {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationController = new RegistrationBasicInformationController(this);
        mDsmApplication.registerController(RegistrationBasicInformationController.TAG, mRegistrationBasicInformationController);
    }

    private void loadView(View view) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationMainLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_relativelayout_for_itself);

        mRegistrationEnterYourBasicInformationLabel = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_textview_for_headerlabel);

        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_firstname);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_lastname);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_dob);

        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_gender);

        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_phonenumber);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_nickname);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText
                .setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText
                .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                            if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob.isEnabled() ) {
                                mRegistrationBasicInformationController.OnCalendarDateTimeIconClicked();
                                ViewUtils.hideVirturalKeyboard((EditText) textView);
                            } else {
                                mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText.requestFocus();
                                ViewUtils.showVirturalKeyboard(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_email);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_practice);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider = (RegistrationItemView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.registration_basicinformation_registrationitemview_for_provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void SetEnterYourBasicInformationLabel(String label) {
        mRegistrationEnterYourBasicInformationLabel.setText(label);
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreateFirstNameItemView(String label, int type, String value,
                                                         int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName.SetValue(value);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName.SetValidationId(validationId,
                IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_TEXTFIELD);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreateLastNameItemView(String label, int type, String value,
                                                        int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName.SetValue(value);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName.SetValidationId(validationId, IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_TEXTFIELD);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreateNickNameItemView(String label, int type, String value, int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName.SetValue(value);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName.SetValidationId(validationId, IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_TEXTFIELD);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreatePracticeItemView(String label, int type, IStringList
            valuesList, String defaultValue, int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice.SetValueList(type, valuesList);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice.SetValidationId(validationId,
                IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_LIST);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreateProviderItemView(String label, int type, IStringList
            valuesList, String defaultValue, int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider.SetValueList(type, valuesList);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider.SetValidationId(validationId,
                IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_LIST);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void ShowPracticeItemView() {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void ShowProviderItemView() {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void RefreshScreen() {
        // NA
    }

    @Override
    public void SetGender(int isMale) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.SetValueForSwitch(isMale);
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreateDobItemView(String label, int type, String value,
                                                   int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob.SetValidationId(validationId, IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_TEXTFIELD);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob.SetValue(value);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreatePhoneNumberItemView(String label, int type, String value, int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber.SetValue(value);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber.SetValidationId(validationId, IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_TEXTFIELD);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreateEmailItemView(String label, int type, String value,
                                                     int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail.SetValue(value);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail.SetValidationId(validationId,
                IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_TEXTFIELD);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail.mRegistrationItemTextTypeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegistrationItemView CreateGenderItemView(String label, int type,
                                                      IStringList valueList, int validationId, int GenderType) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.SetEventListener(this);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.SetLabel(label);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.SetValidationId(validationId,
                IRegistrationItemView.VALUETYPE_RADIO_BUTTON);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.SetValueList(type, valueList);
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.clearRadioButtons();
        mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.SetValueForSwitch(GenderType);
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender;
    }

    @Override
    public void OnErrorIconClick(int validationId) {
        //NA
    }

    @Override
    public void OnCalendarIconClick() {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationController.OnCalendarDateTimeIconClicked();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnSwitchButtonClick(int validationId, boolean isChecked) {
        //NA
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRegistrationItemEditCompleted(String content, int validationId) {
        mRegistrationBasicInformationController.OnRegistrationItemEditCompleted(validationId, content);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnSpinnerItemSelected(int validationId, int position) {
        switch (validationId) {
            case RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_PRACTICE:
                mRegistrationBasicInformationController.OnPracticeItemSelected(position);
                break;

            case RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_PROVIDER:
                mRegistrationBasicInformationController.OnProviderItemSelected(position);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Presenter GetPresenter() {
        return mRegistrationBasicInformationController;
    }

    @Override
    public String GetClassName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        OnDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnDestroy() {
        mRegistrationEnterYourBasicInformationLabel = null;
        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForFirstName = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForLastName = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForNickName = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPhoneNumber = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForEmail = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForGender = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForPractice = null;
        }

        if (mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider != null) {
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider.OnDestroy();
            mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForProvider = null;
        }

        ViewUtils.UnbindReferences(mRegistrationBasicInformationMainLayout);
        ViewUtils.UnbindReferences(getView());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            CustomTextInputEditText editText = (CustomTextInputEditText) view;

            mRegistrationBasicInformationController.OnRegistrationItemEditCompleted((int) view.getTag()
                    , editText.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the codes please. It is hard to evaluate just with description.

Comment: @Subhechhu Khanal  mRegistrationBasicInformationItemForDob is for the calender. RegistrationItemView is my class for editext where I am reusing everywhere. I tried to post the code of RegistrationItemView but since it has many lines of code it didnt allow me to post the same. If ypu will give your email id I can send it. Remember I am facing this issue only in android 7.0 OS.